# continuity NOT using epsilon delta (using uniform continuity to show continuity of a subset)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This was an part of an exam problem that I got wrong:

> Given $f:(0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{x}$. Determine if it possible to define *f* at x = 0 to make it continuous at x = 0. If so, what is $f(0)$? Using those answers, determine if $f$ is uniformly continuous in (0,1]. Justify your answer.

I have an understanding on show this using an epsilon delta proof, but I am not sure how to show it using other methods. (ie algebra of limits and continuity, compact sets etc)

Some thoughts/questions that I have:

- we want $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0)$ to show continuity at the point. Then, since we know, $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$, we then clearly want to define $f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$. I understand this part.
- At the same time, aren't all compact sets uniformly continuous? So, in the case of [0,1] (closed and bounded), if we show that interval is closed and bounded, we have shown continuity and thus the previous step is trivial?
- How does the continuity of [0,1] and specifically at x=0 relate to the continuity of (0,1]?

Comment: It is not intervals which are (uniformly) continuous, but functions defined on these intervals. You can use *Heine's theorem*: Continuous maps defined on a compact metric space with values in a metric space are uniformly continuous.

Comment: For Heine's theorem, we see that [0,1] is a compact metric space. Are you trying to say the map is not continuous in this case, so we need to map f(0) to a specific point to make the mapping continuous?

Comment: No, you've found the value that makes $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$, so it is uniformly  continuous on this interval by Heine's theorem.

Comment: ahh got it thank you